# Card Group Schedule

Tags: algorithmic-game-theory

There are 12 couples in a card group.  Once a month, 4 card games are scheduled at different locations. Each game consists of a host couple and 2 guest couples (3 couples total).
I am looking for an annual schedule that: 
1.  Assigns hosting duty to all couples equitably,
2.  No couple hosts 2 consecutive months,
3.  Pairs the host and guest couples so that no 2 couples play with each other 2 consecutive months, and
4.  Allows as few repeat pairings as possible.

I'm not great at math so if you could, please keep your answer as simple as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics SE. For starter, 12 couples in the card group will held 12 meeting in a year (once a month). So all couple will host once. This takes care of conditions 1 and 2.

Comment: @AlainRemillard, all couples will host four times yearly.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof thank's, I misread the question

Answer (score 0):

*This schedule is not perfect, as each couple only gets to play with $6$ other couples (twice with each of them), but it does meet the other requirements.*

Give each couple a hat with a number ranging from $1$ to $12$. Couples with hat numbers $1, 4, 7, 10$ are hosts, while hats $2$ and $3$ join $1$, $5$ and $6$ join $4$ et cetera.

After the game, we do the following reassignment of hats:

$$\begin{array}{c c} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\ 2 & 6 & 10 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 12 & 1 & 11 & 9 & 4\end{array}$$

i.e. whoever has hat $1$ gives it to the couple with hat $2$, the couple with hat $4$ passes it to the holders of hat $5$ and so on.

Now, again, for the second game, couples with hat numbers $1, 4, 7, 10$ are hosts, while hats $2$ and $3$ join $1$, $5$ and $6$ join $4$ et cetera.

This reassignment is a $12-cycle$, which means each couple will get their original hat again after exactly $12$ months. The matchups at that point (after one year) will be identical again, but you asked for an annual schedule.

As illustration, here are the matchups for one year:

$ \tiny\left(\begin{array}{c| |cc|c||cc|c||cc|c||cc} \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Lopez}\\ \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Davidsen}\\ \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Erdos}\\ \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Caesar}\\ \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Jones}\\ \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Khan}\\ \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Indra}\\ \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Adler}\\ \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Bertoli}\\ \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Franklin}\\ \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Holmes} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Garibaldi}\\ \mathrm{Indra} & \mathrm{Adler} & \mathrm{Erdos} & \mathrm{Lopez} & \mathrm{Davidsen} & \mathrm{Bertoli} & \mathrm{Franklin} & \mathrm{Garibaldi} & \mathrm{Khan} & \mathrm{Caesar} & \mathrm{Jones} & \mathrm{Holmes} \end{array}\right)$

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You state that the schedule you provided is not perfect, as each couple only gets to play with 6 other couples.  Can a schedule be made where each couple gets to play with all other couples?